# LINQPad 6 connecting to SQL Server 2019 Docker got the error when pre-login handshake

Tags: sql-server, docker, linqpad

I can connect from `SQL Server Management Studio` to `SQL Server 2019 docker` hosted in my local machine. However it is failed to connect from `LINQPad 6`.

[image]

The error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then one error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (Provider SSL error 0 - The wait operation timed out)

[image]

and the Advanced settings:

[image]

Any idea please?

Answer (score 3):

My bad. It was Avast anti virus. Looks like it whitelists SQL Server Management Studio but block my Linqpad